# How to have a fixed state on a nav bar

Tags: html, css, nav, effect

I have a webpage with multiple sections. We can navigate from one section to another with a nav bar fixed at the top of the page (with sticky position).
When I am in a certain section on my page, I want the corresponding title on the nav bar to be a different color to indicate that this is the section we are on, but I don't know how to do it.
I need to do it with css only (not javaScript).

Thank you!

Comment: What you're looking for is called a *scrollspy*. Such a thing is not possible in CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the scrollspy plugin

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp